# How to do one single script can automate the entire matches in the mlb site

Tags: automated-testing

I’m testing baseball reporter software.And its windows based application. I'm using winium tool with java lanuguge for automate the app. It’s a kind of reporter software, while a match going on, the reporter will sit into the gallery and  enter the each commentary, this is how our application works each ball by ball.  How I have been testing is taking a previously entered game from mlb.com and entering that commentary into my app.

- First I add the offensive players and defensive players,
- Then I add the umpires and weather report.
- After that I entered each commentary report each ball by ball.

I’m trying to automate this process.

I have tried automating by taking one of yesterdays matches and entering that commentary in my application. Then I automated a comparison between the match I entered and manually and the one I entered with the automation.

Finally I checked the scores, with the mlb site and our application. It's only for that one match. I don't know how to do other matches for automation. If I want to do automate again I have to enter the full script, which will take more time.

I'm looking forward to make automation effective of my application.

I am uable to find a solution for my issue. Recently, I wrote the code for automate one play by play commentory in the mlb site and checks the score with our application and mlb site contents. But the real issue is that I can't automate other games in the mlb site If I need to automate , I need to write again and again for each and every game. my senior check my code and told that this is hard coding. he told me to get a idea about with one single script can automate the each and every match..how it is possible ? it is better useful for the future..

Comment: I've edited your post to make it clearer what you are asking. If this is not what you mean, you can revert my edits.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you want a data driven test.

The long answer is that how you write the test depends a lot on how your software is set up. If it uses an API to communicate, that's easy - you automate the API to send and receive data to enter the match information. I suspect that you can get the information from the MLB site in some kind of easy to manipulate format.

If the app doesn't use an API a data driven test will be harder to write and much less reliable, but it can still be done.

If you don't understand how to write data driven tests, you should consider doing some research online before you start automating.

Comment: Our app uses API . so I am not getting how to automate those API..If it is a more effective automation approach. is it can automated for every match with one single script

Comment: You automate sending the requests and check that the responses match your expectations. I'd suggest a web search for automated API testing as a starting point.