# Does One single script can automate entire matches?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am automating my windows application. My applications are sports related reporter software. In baseball reporter application i will do testing by the following way :  I do enter the commentary from mlb site and check the results while I enter the commentaries are correct.

Here I am automating this process. But actual issue is I can automate only particular match only. I am trying to find a solution for one single script can automate the entire matches. My senior who suggested me to take an excel contain a match **commentary details , player names, umpires names** and write the script for entire code.

My friend who suggested me : **you need to follow data driven approach for this**

1. Create a generic script that gets the actual values from the
   application..
2. Place all the expected values in an excel sheet.
3. Compare the actual and expected.
4. For every game u can change the values in the excel sheet. with this u can have one script automating all the games.

Still I'm unable to start writing the code. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do one single script can automate the entire matches in the mlb site](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/34186/how-to-do-one-single-script-can-automate-the-entire-matches-in-the-mlb-site)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data driven approach for this.

For automating the windows based application you can use either **Sikuli or Winum** to automation with selenium webdriver.

Use the following steps:

```
- Write the automation script Java to get all the values from the application
- Integrate with selenium webdriver and run the code
- Write the output of the code in another excel file.
- Compare the output file with the actual values.
```

If you have decided to use sikuli then follow the below steps:

- Any IDE to create project like Eclipse, NetBeans… etc.
- All Selenium related jar files.
- Sikuli-script.jar file
- All the above jar files should get added to the build path.
- Any Screen capturing tool.

Comment: How to get values from the application ?

Comment: Use Dataprovider :                                                                              FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(new File("./data/"+dataSheetName+".xlsx"));                                                                                 //To write the values that you got from the application into a excel file

Answer (score 0):

Single script for the entire match is **NOT A GOOD SOLUTION.**
More division of scenarios better always. First, divide all scenarios possible and slowly start one by one, this will give you confidence.
Later if you want or if your lead wants, you can integrate into a single script but not recommendable.